# How to programmatically get list of available image styles

Tags: 8, media

I'm able to get a list of fields using

```
$fields = array_keys(\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'ce_meeting'));
```

But is there a way to get a list of Image Styles instead?
Something similar to

```
$fields = array_keys(\Drupal::entityManager()->getImageStyles());
```

to spit out an array

```
['thumbnail','original','medium','large','small']
```

Is there a function to display a list of available image styles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

and load all image style with

```
$styles = ImageStyle::loadMultiple();
```

Also you can use  [entity_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load_multiple/8.1.x)  with

```
 styles = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->loadMultiple();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get a list of all image styles with an entity query:

```
$image_styles = \Drupal::entityQuery('image_style')
        ->execute();
```

If you query the config entity `image_style`, you get an array with a list of available image styles.

If you use `loadMultiple()` on the config entity, you get an array with the loaded config objects. Use this, if you need the configurations.

If you only need a list, use entity query, because this is faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get it with Drush on the CLI, use:

`drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->loadMultiple()));"`